# Filament Select with getSearchResultsUsing value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to figure something over last 3 days and having hard times figuring out. I would appreciate if someone could point me in right direction.
I have Filament Repeater with Select for products search & select. I can search by Name, Barcode etc and. Picked product from the list shows product "Name" in select field. But once "Order" is saved to db and Edit form opened, I get "article_code" instead product "Name" in select field.

I am stuck with getSearchResultsUsing to limit what I am searching by.

```php
  // Repeater::make('orderingItems')
  // ->relationship()
  // ->schema([
  // ...
      Select::make('article')
      ->label(__('Select article'))
      // ->options(StoreArticles::all())  /// This works sort of..
      ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $query) => StoreArticles::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->pluck('name', 'article_code'))
      ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Forms\Set $set, Get $get) {
          ray("Picked article: " . $state);
          // do some other stuff               
      })
      ->searchable(['article_code', 'name','barkod'])
      ->columnSpan(4)
      ->required(),
// ])
```

My Orders model has relation:

```php
public function orderingItems(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StoreArticles::class, 'order');
    }
```

Example what it looks like when Edit form is opened and when I add new article to it. Desired result is to show full product name in "Article Name" field.

[image]

There are maybe other ways for doing same thing. I have 1000 different articles and preloading isn't the option. I am kind of limited on getSearchResultsUsing.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to limit the number of records retrieved in the search. You can achieve this in a few ways:

The first method involves using `->optionsLimit()`:

```
Select::make('article')
  ->label(__('Select article'))
  ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $query) => StoreArticles::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->pluck('name', 'article_code'))
  ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Forms\Set $set, Get $get) {
      ray("Picked article: " . $state);
      // do some other stuff               
  })
  ->searchable(['article_code', 'name','barkod'])
  ->columnSpan(4)
  ->optionsLimit(20)
  ->required(),
```

The second one is use a `limit` in the query. To do that and simplify your code, use [getSearchResultsUsing](https://docs.laravel-filament.cn/docs/forms/fields/select/#returning-custom-search-results)*****:

```
Select::make('article')
  ->label(__('Select article'))
  ->getSearchResultsUsing(fn (string $query) => 
  StoreArticles::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->limit(20)->pluck('name', 'article_code'))
  ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Forms\Set $set, Get $get) {
      ray("Picked article: " . $state);
  })
  ->searchable(['article_code', 'name','barkod'])
  ->columnSpan(4)
  ->required()
```

You can also load the select without records. Only search and show records after the user types 3 or 4 characters (while also limiting the retrieved records).

You can also use a [debounce](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#debouncing-reactive-fields) to make the page smoother. This means the component will wait a few seconds after the user stops typing in the search input before sending the request to the backend. With fewer requests, there are fewer component render.

```
Select::make('article')
   ...
   ->searchDebounce(1200)
```

Comment: Thank you Liucas, I've ended up using ->options(....)  and ->optionsLimit(20). I've no clue and have not seen that ->optionsLimit(20) exists. Thank you for this tip. 
SearchDebounce works only in case of ->getSearchResultsUsing

I am still getting a bit of issue with getSearchResultsUsing, where name isnt shown in Select box when article is saved and form is reloaded. It brings "article_code" instead.  As shown on image in my question on the top.

Comment: I need to see what impact will  ->optionsLimit(20) have and will that still load all data or set limit on query itself.